# Слияние веток в Git при обновлении удаленного хостинга

Tags: git, git-merge

Внесите, пожалуйста, ясность. Пусть есть 2 ветки main и feature. Есть программист, который работает в ветке feature над какой-то задачей. В это время в ветке main на удаленном хостинге появляется еще 1 коммит. Но программист этого может и не знать. Каким образом тогда готовую фичу в ветке feature замерджить в основную ветку, которая на удаленном хостинге уже обновлена?

Comment: прежде чем мерджить нужно обновить тут ветку, куда мердж. Может оно и не будет мерджится кстати, если не обновить.

Comment: @Эникейщик А как обновить только одну ветку? Я знаю, что если из гита вызвать git pull, то произойдет fetch всего проекта.

Comment: а чем вам мешает обновление всего проекта? Особенно, если у вас всего-то две ветки. Как обновить только одну ветку, а так же много других интересных вещей, можно наверняка узнать из документации. А я вот так сходу не скажу.

Comment: Если я захочу обновить весь проект, мне придется сначала пушить свою ветку, потом качать весь проект(с новой версией главной ветки), мерджить и обратно отправлять на удаленный хостинг. А так можно просто обновить главную ветку, замерджить и сразу все отправить.

Comment: То ли у вас странные процедуры, то ли странное представление о том как работает git

Comment: если вы хотите делать мерж, то никто вам ничего не помешает. обновляете `git fetch server main` и мержите `git merge server/main`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Правильно я понимаю, что первая команда обновит main, а вторая принимает попытку замерджить... Но ведь в таком случае, если мы отим замерджить именно feature в мастер, нам нужно находится в этот момент в main и вторая команда принимает вид git merge feature

Comment: вы у себя локально мержите находясь в своей нити, потом если надо дальше делаете пуш. я пока ответ уже нарисовал, посмотрите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер ситуация :

```
-T - main    - new
 L - feature - new
```

Ваша рабочая станция :

```
-T - server/main
 L - feature     - new
```

Обновляете у себя данные на сервере

```
git fetch server main

-T - server/main - new
 L - feature     - new
```

Мержите у себя локально свою нить с main

```
git merge server/main

-T - server/main - new
 |                      \
 L - feature     - new - merged
```

Дальше можете продолжать работать и/или пушить на сервер свою свежую нить.